# when using signedTransaction(),.Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: web3js, ether

i want to swap eth for DAI on Rinkeby in Uniswap.Here is my code:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import EthTx from "ethereumjs-tx";

const daiExchangeAddress = "0x77dB9C915809e7BE439D2AB21032B1b8B58F6891";
const daiExchangeAbi =
  '[{"name": "TokenPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "EthPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "AddLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "RemoveLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Transfer", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Approval", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "setup", "outputs": [], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 175875}, {"name": "addLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_liquidity"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 82605}, {"name": "removeLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "amount"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 116814}, {"name": "__default__", "outputs": [], "inputs": [], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function"}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12757}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12965}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50463}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50671}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47503}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47712}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50175}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50384}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51007}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51098}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 54928}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 55019}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49342}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49532}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53233}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53423}, {"name": "getEthToTokenInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5542}, {"name": "getEthToTokenOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6872}, {"name": "getTokenToEthInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5637}, {"name": "getTokenToEthOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6897}, {"name": "tokenAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1413}, {"name": "factoryAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1443}, {"name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1645}, {"name": "transfer", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 75034}, {"name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 110907}, {"name": "approve", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 38769}, {"name": "allowance", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1925}, {"name": "name", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1623}, {"name": "symbol", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1653}, {"name": "decimals", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1683}, {"name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1713}]';

const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/...")
);
const addressFrom = "0x19870Ac6C53ed81cAf1e514Bcaf00970F4a....";
const privKey ="903b7cd94bda09fa1d750f51c38aa84cc6e8c0713b6ef00c84e7bde......";
const daiExchangeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
  JSON.parse(daiExchangeAbi),
  daiExchangeAddress
)
const ETH_SOLD = web3.utils.toHex(10000000000000000); // 0.01ETH
const MIN_TOKENS = web3.utils.toHex(0.2 * 10 ** 18); // 0.2 DAI
const DEADLINE = 1633964817; 

const exchangeEncodedABI = daiExchangeContract.methods
  .ethToTokenSwapInput(MIN_TOKENS, DEADLINE)
  .encodeABI();

function sendSignedTx(transactionObject, cb) {
  let transaction = new EthTx(transactionObject);
  const privateKey = new Buffer.from(privKey, "hex");
  transaction.sign(privateKey);
  const serializedEthTx = transaction.serialize().toString("hex");
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedEthTx}`, cb);
}

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(transactionNonce => {
    const transactionObject = {
      "chainId": 4,
      "nonce":  web3.utils.toHex(transactionNonce),
      "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(6000000),
      "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(1000000000),
      "to": daiExchangeAddress,
      "from": addressFrom,
      "data": exchangeEncodedABI,
      "value": ETH_SOLD
    };
  
    sendSignedTx(transactionObject, function(error, result){
      if(error) return console.log("error ===>", error);
      console.log("sent ===>", result);
    })
});
```

When run the code, I get Txhash:0x755be840a75ecaed149473ad36a093c5f69cb2427bbbab5bcde41606d5a084ca;
but when calling `` web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedEthTx}`, cb); ``

error shows:

> (node:828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:828) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I don't know where it goes wrong.

Comment: it is strange that if i code the transactionObject.data="0x123123",not use the given abi,the transaction will be success.

Comment: Looking at the transaction hash it seems to be a bug in the contract code. Can't check anything else because the contracts don't have the source code verified.

Comment: yeah, i thing u r right ,  it is caused by the bug in the contract, thank you